# There should be a penalty when closing other people's question

Tags: discussion

Saw this post today

[Why is printing "B" dramatically slower than printing "#"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947452/why-is-printing-b-dramatically-slower-than-printing)

So apparently even one of the answerer tried to close this question as "offtopic"

To close a question, we need at least five people. For each people voting to close, minus as many karma as the question receives. The closers must be punished for each upvoters who wanted to see this question answered. Because no one can answer a closed question anymore after closing it.

If a question is indeed bad, it's not going to receive upvotes anyway. So no worries for correct closing,

But if a good question needs more capable people providing answers, there will be consequences for wrongfully closing it. A heavily upvoted question proved its value and closing it contributes nothing but negative value. One should be responsible for their action and intention

How about that?

Comment: Why should the users who vote to close be penalized?  Do you have any reasons for requesting this?  Any examples of incorrectly closed question. etc?  In it's current form, I don't see much of a discussion her.

Comment: @bluefeet yes. see my edited post.

Comment: the community voted to close and then reopen the question, I still don't see why anyone should be penalized for voting to close this?

Comment: One might choose to answer an _off-topic_ question while maintaining that it's _off-topic_ and vote-to-close it.

Comment: @bluefeet that's because this question received external attention (reddit, hacker news, etc.). How many good question were buried because out there without noticing?

Comment: @devnull How can you even answer a closed question?

Comment: @est - He said *off-topic* not *closed*. (answering before it is closed)

Comment: @est And now you are drawing attention to it on meta, where meta users will have eyes on it and the power to vote to close it as well.  But you still aren't providing any reasons for people to be penalized for using their privileges to vote to close.

Comment: Penalize Oded for closing [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222930/187824 "10K only").

Comment: @bluefeet people don't provide reasons to close questions either.  Constructive criticism is rare these days. If the question is indeed off topic, I don't see why not close it.

Comment: @est Provided a reason to close question, down vote etc is not required.

Comment: I think you're saying in [your second comment here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222929/there-should-be-a-penalty-when-closing-other-peoples-question#comment725818_222929) that you think the question was closed due to its high visibility on external sites. It's far, far more likely that the _upvotes_ are a result of that. Questions that get noticed by external sites tend to become very popular in terms of views and upvotes, regardless of their quality. Close votes will come from attention on SO itself or MSO.

Answer (score 8):

> The closers must be punished for each upvoters who wanted to see this question answered. Because no one can answer a closed question anymore after closing it.

The whole point of closing is indeed that "no one can answer a closed question anymore after closing it".

We close such questions so they do not get any additional answers (or any at all), to discourage people asking questions that do not belong.

---

Penalizing people for voting to close means that a lot less stuff will get closed. Including very low quality and off-topic posts.

The implementation of this suggestion would be counter productive.

---

By all means, if you can show how this would be a net **gain** for the community, feel free to explain how.

Comment: the intention was good, but in practice many people just bindly close many questions they don't understand. How to solve that?

Comment: @est - By flagging/voting to reopen the question.

Comment: @est - How do you know that's the reason? Lots of questions get closed because they are not answerable/understandable. Most people wouldn't bother to try and improve their posts if they were not put on-hold/closed.

Comment: @hims056 Can't solve the bad habit of random closing other people's question because its-not-my-problem mentality. If you ever have that experience you'd know what I am saying.

Comment: @est - You are making an assumption. If it **isn't** an assumption, I would like to see your data.

Comment: @Oded Yes I tried to provide data, but quantitative measurement of "good" question is not easy. I myself had this experience, asked each closer exact reason, they just shrugged and said sorry not my problem.

Comment: @est - nor does a single question that exhibits the issue (which is debatable, but regardless) means there is a widespread trend.

Comment: @est even if some people have `bad habit of random closing other people's question`(to which I disagree), most of them can only flag them. There are moderators, chosen by community, who can dispute wrong flags.

Comment: @Oded How about this: If a question is indeed bad, it's not going to receive upvote anyway. So no worries for correct closing, But if a good question needs to be answered, there will be consequences for wrongfully closing it. A heavily upvoted question proved its value and closing it contributes nothing but negative value. One should be responsible for their action and intention, no?

Comment: @est - there is a reason why 5 community members are required for closing. Those are the checks and balances. If a question is good, even if someone casts a close vote, it will not get closed. On the other hand, a bad question, even if it does have upvotes, has a good chance of getting closed. I still fail to see how penalizing people for voting to close achieves anything.

Comment: "A heavily upvoted question proved its value and closing it contributes nothing but negative value" - that is not quite right either. Heavily upvoted questions can be **popular** without being a good fit or good for the site in the longer term.

Comment: @Oded Okay, can you reason the logic behind closing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21947452/revisions)? I don't see anything obviously wrong with the question itself.

Comment: @est - that question is not closed.

Comment: @Oded I mean the motivation of the closing attempt by five people. One of them is the answerer. Don't you think the gamification should be punished? Answer fist, close later, rep karma. If can't answer, close it so nobody can answer.

Comment: @est - if the question gets deleted, the rep evaporates with it. Most people learn from that quickly enough.